# Ideal way to invoke method from multiple interface implementation

Tags: java

An interface with multiple implementations.

```
    public interface A {

        void process();
    }

    public class FirstImplementation implements A{

        void process(){
           // do something 
        }

    }

    public class SecondImplementation implements A{

        void process(){
           // do something else
        }

    }
```

To invoke the method from both implementation instances, i can do the following

```
    A a1 = new FirstImplementation();
    a1.process();

    A a2 = new SecondImplementation();
    a2.process();

    // Similarly, a3.process() for another implementation
```

For a use case where the method (with different action in each implementation) needs to be invoked from all the implementations in a sequential manner, is there a better way or an existing design pattern?

Comment: I'm not sure that the same `process()` would be invoked in your code snippet above.  Why would you expect that to be the case?

Comment: So you basically ask how to get all classes that implement a specific interface? Or even all reachable objects?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry for the confusion. I just edited the title.

Comment: @Turing85 yep. Instead of invoking each implementation object separately, is there an easy way to call the method on all available objects that implements that interface?

Comment: Nope. You will have to create your own bookkeeping. To the best of my knowledge, there is no hard way to guarantee that your bookkeeping will actually be able to record all objects since you need the "help" of the implementing classes (i.e. you need to "record" each object in some kind of list within each constructor call). This approach uses preemitve object leakage and should therefore not be used in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: Are you looking for [chain of responsibility](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility) design pattern?